# Starting and Stopping Audio Using Swipe Gestures

Tags: ios

I'm working on a little app for my daughter to play with and I'm having a slight issue with starting and stopping the sound. I have coded it now where it does play the different sounds as you swipe from one page to the next but they overlap. I'm trying to figure out how to stop the previous sound and start the next one as the page is swiped back and forth. Here is what I have:

```
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize imageview;

int imageIndex = 0;

- (IBAction)handleSwipe:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {
//NSLog(@"swiped");


UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection direction =
[(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) sender direction];

switch (direction) {
    case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft:
        imageIndex++;
        break;
    case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight:
        imageIndex--;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
[self doit];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
imageIndex = -1;

imageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void) doit {
NSArray *images= [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                  @"bee.png",
                  @"cow.png",
                  @"cat.png",
                  @"dog.png",
                  @"elephant.png",
                  @"goat.png",
                  @"horse.png",
                  @"lion.png",
                  @"monkey.png",
                  @"pig.png",
                  @"rooster.png",
                  @"sheep.png",
                  @"snake.png",
                  @"squirrel.png",
                  @"tiger.png",
                  @"wolf.png", nil];

NSArray *audio= [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                 @"Bee",
                 @"Cow",
                 @"Cat",
                 @"Dog",
                 @"Elephant",
                 @"Goat",
                 @"Horse",
                 @"Lion",
                 @"Monkey",
                 @"Pig",
                 @"Rooster",
                 @"Sheep",
                 @"Snake",
                 @"Squirrel",
                 @"Tiger",
                 @"Wolf", nil];
imageIndex = (imageIndex < 0) ? ([images count] -1):
imageIndex % [images count];
imageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:imageIndex]];


//audio here
NSString *str = [audio objectAtIndex:imageIndex];
CFStringRef string =  (__bridge CFStringRef) str;

CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
CFURLRef soundeFileURLRef;
soundeFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) string, CFSTR ("mp3"), NULL);
UInt32 soundID;
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundeFileURLRef, &soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
```

Comment: Nevermind I was able to get this working.